# manually opening ports on windows 7 64 bit to run emit android app and emit server on windows?

Tags: android, tcp, routes, udp, wifi

How should I manually open ports TCP 1554 and udp 2000-2006 for IP 192.168.0.1 . I have  a Windows 7 64 bit Home Premium and a i5 processor laptop.

I want to do this in order to use the  Emit Android app and the server software for Windows. Whenever I try to install the server, this is the message I get

"unable to configure your router to open ports

you have to manually open ports tcp 1554 and udp 2000-2006 for ip 192.168.0.1 "

This Emit software can be used to stream music from the pc library directly to your Android device, without actually copying the files via local wifi network.